# Stop google voice from prompting me: New: Receive SMS and Voicemail in Hangouts!

Tags: google-voice

Whenever I log in to [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com) it keeps prompting me

> New: Receive SMS and Voicemail in Hangouts!

But every time I close it, it comes back. How do I get rid of it? There's a known issue that using Hangouts to receive SMS with Sprint doesn't work, so I just want to stop this prompt from reappearing every time I login.

Note: This is in regards to voice.google.com - not an app.